# GoogleTest C++ Framework Incompatible With XCode 4.5.2 and OSX 10.8.2

Tags: xcode

I am trying to follow the instructions [mentioned here](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/XcodeGuide) for setting up Google's C++ framework in XCode Version 4.5.2 (4G2008a).

First, I got `"The run destination My Mac 64-bit is not valid for Running the scheme 'gtest-framework'"`. The answers here [Xcode 4 - The selected run destination is not valid for this action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319251/xcode-4-the-selected-run-destination-is-not-valid-for-this-action) are not working for me. I was able to change the build SDK following the instructions here [Unable to build using Xcode 4 - The selected run destination is not valid for this action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422066/unable-to-build-using-xcode-4-the-selected-run-destination-is-not-valid-for-th), except this resulted in many build failures such as `"Unsupported compiler '4.0' selected for architecture 'x86_64'"` and `"Unsupported compiler '4.0' selected for architecture 'i386'"`

I've changed nothing out of the box, so this is very frustrating that I cannot seem to get this to build.

Details of Machine:
64bit
Mac OSX 10.8.2
Build 12C3006

Details of XCode:
Version 4.5.2 (4G2008a)

Comment: More specific information is required.  What version of OS X are you using?  **This being in the title is not acceptable since I just missed it.**  Are we talking about 64-bit kernel or 32-bit kernel that makes a difference.  I suggest you look for updated instructions to compile that framework my guess it hasn't been updated to even support 10.8.2 and unless you have the knowledge required to fix it will run into dozens of problems like your facing.

Comment: It looks kind of like http://code.google.com/p/googletest/issues/detail?id=400

Comment: So did you apply the patch?

Comment: The patch is not from Google officially and as such I do not trust it.